# Javascript Visualforce update object not working

Tags: visualforce, apex

I am new in visualforce apex development, and I am trying to update object of salesforce but its throwing error: "Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"".
Please help me out.
I am trying the below code:

```
     function updateAccounts(terrId,accId){
     var acc=[]; 
      var contact = new sforce.SObject("ObjectTerritory2Association");
       contact.objectid = accId;
       contact.territory2id = terrId; 
       acc.push(contact);
       sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
       if(terrId!="")
          sforce.connection.update(acc);
        else
          sforce.connection.delete(acc);

    }
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this problem. I don't remember the exact reason it was happening - something about being a Community User vs. a Salesforce user.

I recommend using [JavaScript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm) instead.